# Test with RSpec if graphQL field method argument default value is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, graphql

How do I write a test to check the default values of a field methods argument?

```rb
    field :foo, String, null: false do
      argument my_argument, Int, required: true
      argument my_other_argument, Boolean, required: false
    end

    def foo(my_argument:, my_other_argument: true)
      <some code>
    end
```

My attempts at RSpec test:

```rb
    field :foo, "String!" do
      it "test that my_other_argument has a default value of true"
       resolve(args: {my_argument: 10}) # Note that my_other_argument is not given a value

       expect(args[:my_other_argument]).to eq(true)
      end
    end
```

The above example fails and throws this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `args'
```

So to boil it down - can't seem to figure out how this row should be written:

```
expect(args[:my_other_argument]).to eq(true)
```

... or maybe I am at the complete wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

If `foo` is calling another method, you could use `recieve` and `with`. Something like...

```
class Foo
  def bar(my_other_argument: true)
    baz(my_other_argument)
  end

  def baz(val)
    # Stuff
  end
end

describe :bar do
  context 'default values' do
    it 'defaults to true' do
      @foo = Foo.new
      expect(@foo).to receive(:baz).with(true)

      @foo.bar
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It does not look like answers the questions

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about the [Resolvers](https://graphql-ruby.org/fields/resolvers.html). 
You can defined a resolvers for `foo`.

```
class Resolvers::Foo < Resolvers::Base
  argument :my_argument, Int, required: true
  argument :my_other_argument, Boolean, required: false

  def resolve(my_argument:, my_other_argument: true)
    <some code>
  end
end
```

And use it in query file as

```
field :foo, String, resolver: Resolvers::Foo, null: false
```

On the other hand, if you want to test some fields with arguments, it will be better if you make a query with such arguments like:

```
foo(my_argument: $my_argument, my_other_argument: $my_other_argument)
```

`$my_argument` and `$my_other_argument` are the arguments you want to test with.
There are more details in the doc of [Graphql testing](https://graphql-ruby.org/testing/integration_tests.html)